# 90s (or earlier) PC fantasy game, collecting crystals and building your base in the sky

Tags: story-identification, video-games

I remember playing a game when I was young, probably around 15-18 years ago.

It was some sort of an RTS-style game that took place in the sky. You could collect these crystal-like things from nodes that also floated around. And if I remember correctly, could construct an entire base in the sky.

More things I remember:

- I think you had some sort of mules that could collect the crystals from the nodes.
- I think you also had enemies on separate "islands". I think one of them was a scorpion-like enemy.
- You could build bridges in the sky. I remember that after some time, some bridges would collapse.
- Top-down view

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (video game) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11995/how-to-ask-a-good-video-game-story-id-question)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like **Netstorm: Islands at War**.

- Played 15 to 18 years ago - it was released in 1997, so entirely possible
- Took place in the sky - check
- Collect crystals - check
- Construct bases - well, towers
- Had mules - the workers were horse/mule type characters
- Enemies on separate islands - check
- Scorpion-like enemy - I could see how some of the enemies could resemble a robot scorpion.
- build bridges - check, that would fall down: they could be taken over, I can't remember if they could be destroyed.
- Top-down view - see below:

[image: Top-down view of the edge of a map, depicting a floating island with several constructions]
[image: Netstorm poster, night sky with a lightning bolt]